# Async polling with Play framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

How do you poll a function asynchronously in Play?

What I need to do:

1. Client makes a request to Play application.
2. Play application checks a function at fixed intervals.
3. If function returns true, return the request immediately, otherwise poll the function again at a later time.

What I got so far:

```
// Controller
public class Application extends Controller {
    // Action
    public static Promise<Result> startPoll(String id) {
        Promise<Boolean> pollPromise = poller(id);
        Promise<Result> resultPromise = pollPromise.map(pollResult -> ok(pollResult));
        return resultPromise;
    }

    private static Promise<Boolean> poller(String id) {
        // TODO How do you poll a function with promise of a boolean?
    }
}
```

The polling should not block other similar requests from completing.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with a recursive function that:
1) returns true when the polled function returns "ready"
2) returns a promise to check later when the polled function returns "not ready"

Example:

In Controller class:

```
public Promise<boolean> processRequest() {
    Task t = new Task;
    t.startTask();
    return taskPoller(t);
}

private Promise<Boolean> taskPoller(Task t) {
    if (t.isDone()) {
        return Promise.promise(()->true);
    } else {
        Promise<Boolean> p = Promise.timeout(true, 100); //100 milliseconds
        return p.map((result) -> taskPoller(t));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to look into WebSockets or make the client poll the server through ajax.
[See Here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaWebSockets)

Comment: There is only one request between a client and the server. The polling happens only within the server. The request returns only after this polling is complete.